# How can I use a QMap to store and look at my data?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT started to try out some things with QMap as it seems like a useful tool. I already read some other forum threads but I wasnt able to answer my question. The user is supposed to add and edit different shapes via the GUI. For the shapes I first wrote an abstract base class:

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QMap>
 class Base
{
 protected:
     QVariantMap m_properties;
     QString m_key;
     void setKey(const QString& key){
         this->m_key=key;
     }
public:
     Base(){}
     virtual ~Base(){}
     QString key(){
         return m_key;
     }
     void setProperty(QString key, QVariant variant){
         m_properties[key]=variant;
     }
     virtual void toRTC()=0;
};

#endif // BASE_H
```

one example of a subclass is an ellipse with the following cpp file:

```
#include "ellipse.h"

Ellipse::Ellipse(int Start_x, int Start_y, int Rad_x, int Rad_y): rad_x(Rad_x), rad_y(Rad_y), start_x(Start_x), start_y(Start_y)
{
    this->setKey("ellipse");
    this->setProperty("radX", rad_x);
    this->setProperty("radY", rad_y);
    this->setProperty("startX", start_x);
    this->setProperty("startY", start_y);
}


void Ellipse::set_rad_x(int rad_x)
{
    Base::setProperty("radX", rad_x);
}
void Ellipse::set_rad_y(int rad_y)
{
    Base::setProperty("radY", rad_y);
}
void Ellipse::set_start_x(int start_x)
{
    Base::setProperty("startX", start_x);
}
void Ellipse::set_start_y(int start_y)
{
    Base::setProperty("startY", start_y);
}



int Ellipse::get_rad_x()
{
    return m_properties["radX"].toInt();
}

int Ellipse::get_rad_y()
{
    return m_properties["radY"].toInt();
}

int Ellipse::get_start_x()
{
    return m_properties["startX"].toInt();
}

int Ellipse::get_start_y()
{

    return m_properties["startY"].toInt();
}
```

First off, is this a correct approach for the cpp file? I feel my approach is vary laborious.

In my main window file I thought about storing my data in a simple Vector  `QVector<Base *> data_storage;`

```
Ellipse *e_values = new Ellipse(ui->Ellipse_Value_start_x->value(),ui->Ellipse_Value_start_y->value(), ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_x->value(),ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_y->value());

 data_storage.append(e_values);
```

To load the data, I thought it would be a good idea to use the key to check which object of data_storage I want to load, but I don't really know how I can access the data which is connected to my key.

```
    if(data_storage[t]->key()=="ellipse"){
                ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_x->setValue(data_storage[t]->) //how can I access the correct data?
}
```

I feel like I messed up the entire approach, like how to properly use keys, so how would I do that?

Comment: You might do it much simpler. Store your data in the following structure: `QMat<QString, QVariantMap>`, where the key would be a shape name, and value is a list of named properties. You basically don't need classes.

Comment: @vahancho how do you have multiple `Ellipse`s in that scheme?

Comment: @Caleth, if I need to have multiple ellipses, it should be rather `QMultiMap`, e.g. : `map.insert("ellipse", {{"rad_x", 1}, {"rad_y", 2}})` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare all the behaviours you need in the base class. I don't see the need to have `Base` hold the data.

E.g. if you need to be able to read and write the UI, there should be methods to do that.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void toRTC() = 0;
    virtual QVariantMap properties() const = 0;
    virtual void writeUI(form_t * ui) const = 0;
    virtual void readUI(const form_t * ui) = 0;
};

class Ellipse : public Base
{
    int start_x;
    int start_y;
    int rad_x;
    int rad_y;
public:
    void toRTC() final { /* ??? */ }
    QVariantMap properties() const final { 
        return { { "radX", rad_x }, { "radY", rad_y }, 
                 { "startX", start_x }, { "startY", start_y } }; 
    }
    void writeUI(form_t * ui) const final {
        ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_x->setValue(rad_x);
        ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_y->setValue(rad_y);
        ui->Ellipse_Value_start_x->setValue(start_x);
        ui->Ellipse_Value_start_y->setValue(start_y);
    }
    void readUI(const form_t * ui) final {
        rad_x = ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_x->value().toInt();
        rad_y = ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_y->value().toInt();
        start_x = ui->Ellipse_Value_start_x->value().toInt();
        start_y = ui->Ellipse_Value_start_y->value().toInt();
    }
};
```

If you don't want to tie your shapes to the UI, you could define a visitor interface, with a visit method for each shape type.

```
class ShapeVisitor
{
    virtual void accept(Ellipse * ellipse) = 0;
    /* virtual void accept(Rectangle * rectangle) = 0; // etc.. */
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void toRTC() = 0;
    virtual QVariantMap properties() const = 0;
    virtual void visit(ShapeVisitor & visitor) = 0;
};

class Ellipse : public Base
{
public:
    int start_x;
    int start_y;
    int rad_x;
    int rad_y;

    void toRTC() final { /* ??? */ }
    QVariantMap properties() const final { 
        return { { "radX", rad_x }, { "radY", rad_y }, 
                 { "startX", start_x }, { "startY", start_y } }; 
    }
    void visit(ShapeVisitor & visitor) final {
        visitor.accept(this); // calls visitor::accept(Ellipse *)
    }
};

class UIReadVisitor : public ShapeVisitor
{
    form_t * ui
    void accept(Ellipse * ellipse) final {
        ellipse->rad_x = ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_x->value().toInt();
        ellipse->rad_y = ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_y->value().toInt();
        ellipse->start_x = ui->Ellipse_Value_start_x->value().toInt();
        ellipse->start_y = ui->Ellipse_Value_start_y->value().toInt();
    }
}

class UIWriteVisitor : public ShapeVisitor
{
    form_t * ui;
    void accept(Ellipse * ellipse) final {
        ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_x->setValue(ellipse->rad_x);
        ui->Ellipse_Value_rad_y->setValue(ellipse->rad_y);
        ui->Ellipse_Value_start_x->setValue(ellipse->start_x);
        ui->Ellipse_Value_start_y->setValue(ellipse->start_y);
    }
}
```